# how can i get the average of array objects and display them on android text view?

Tags: java, arrays, object, getter-setter

House[] Houses= new House[3];

```
    int houseNum=0;
    while(fsc.hasNext()){
        Houses[houseNum] = new House(); // creates hous einto array
        Houses[houseNum].setAddress(fsc.nextLine());
        Houses[houseNum].setCity(fsc.nextLine());
        Houses[houseNum].setValue(fsc.nextDouble());
        fsc.nextLine();
        Houses[houseNum].setYearBuilt(fsc.nextInt());
        fsc.nextLine();
        Houses[houseNum].setPropertyTaxes(fsc.nextDouble());
        fsc.nextLine();
        Houses[houseNum].setSquareFootage(fsc.nextInt());
        fsc.nextLine();
        tv.append(Houses[houseNum].getAddress() + "\n" );
        tv.append(Houses[houseNum].getCity() + "\n" );
        tv.append(Houses[houseNum].getValue() + "\n" );
        tv.append(Houses[houseNum].getYearBuilt() + "\n" );
        tv.append(Houses[houseNum].getPropertyTaxes() + "\n" );
        tv.append(Houses[houseNum].getSquareFootage() + "\n" );


        houseNum++;
```

}

```
     double sumFootage = 0;                               
    for(int i=0; i < houseNum ; i++){                     
        sumFootage += Houses[houseNum].getSquareFootage();
    }                                                     
    double averageFootage= sumFootage/houseNum;           
    tv.append("Average Footage:" + averageFootage);
```

i am using adroid studio to display this in text. i am confused on how to do the follwoing:
Display the average square footage of the three houses (as a real number) in the TextView . Display this value to three decimal places (e.g., 1000.321).
Display  the  weighted  average  of  the  property  taxes  with  respect  to  the  square  footage  for  the  three
houses (as a real number) in the TextView below the house data.
[error message i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWbhD.png)

Comment: Create a variable outside the loop `Double combinedFootage = 0;` then inside the `for` loop once you have added the footage, simply use `combinedFoorage += Houses[houseNum].getSquareFootage();` then after/outside the loop simply use `Double averageFootage = combinedFoorage/(houseNum+1);` and `tv.append("Average footage: " + averageFootage);`

Comment: i tried that but my app crashes when i do that

Comment: what is the type of  fsc provide the part where its declared. Also provide the log when app crash

Comment: // (opens URL file for reading)                      
URL file_url = new URL(inputFile);                 
Scanner fsc = new Scanner(file_url.openStream());

Comment: Please edit your question to show your updated code and the full error. If you get an `InputMismatchException` or an `NoSuchElementException` then you have called `fsc.next...` one too many times in your code, or if you get `NoSuchMethodException` then you have not created a `getSquareFootage()` method in your house class.

Comment: i included the error messagei am getting

Comment: The issue is caused by trying to access an array with a value that is out of bounds. To solve your issue change this `sumFootage += Houses[houseNum].getSquareFootage();` to this `sumFootage += Houses[i].getSquareFootage();` note how we need to use `i` inside that array, not `houseNum`.